# Pandas counting and summing specific conditions

Tags: python, excel, pandas, countif, sumifs

Are there single functions in pandas to perform the equivalents of [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx), which sums over a specific condition and [COUNTIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx), which counts values of specific conditions from Excel?

I know that there are many multiple step functions that can be used for

For example for `sumif` I can use `(df.map(lambda x: condition) or df.size())` then use `.sum()`, and for `countif`, I can use `(groupby functions` and look for my answer or use a filter and the `.count())`.

Is there simple one step process to do these functions where you enter the condition and the dataframe and you get the sum or counted results?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can first make a conditional selection, and sum up the results of the selection using the `sum` function.

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
>> df[df.a > 1].sum()   
a    5
dtype: int64
```

Having more than one condition:

```
>> df[(df.a > 1) & (df.a < 3)].sum()
a    2
dtype: int64
```

If you want to do `COUNTIF`, just replace `sum()` with `count()`

Answer (score 57):

You didn't mention the fancy indexing capabilities of dataframes, e.g.:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"class":[1,1,1,2,2], "value":[1,2,3,4,5]})
>>> df[df["class"]==1].sum()
class    3
value    6
dtype: int64
>>> df[df["class"]==1].sum()["value"]
6
>>> df[df["class"]==1].count()["value"]
3
```

You could replace `df["class"]==1`by another condition.

Answer (score 16):

I usually use numpy sum over the logical condition column:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : [20,24,18,5,78]})
>>> np.sum(df['Age'] > 20)
2
```

This seems to me slightly shorter than the solution presented above

Comment: Actually, one does not have to use numpy here. You can just `sum(df['Age'] > 20)`. The argument is iterable and can be picked up by the built-in function.

Answer (score 3):

For multiple conditions e.g. COUNTIFS/SUMIFS, a convenient method is `query` because it's very fast for large frames (where performance actually matters) and you don't need to worry about parentheses, bitwise-and etc. For example, to compute `=SUMIFS(C2:C8, A2:A8,">1", B2:B8, "<3")`, you can use

```py
df.query("A>1 and B<3")['C'].sum()
# or 
df.iloc[:8].query("A>1 and B<3")['C'].sum()    # where the range is specified as in SUMIFS
```

For COUNTIFS, you can simply sum over the condition. For example, to compute `=COUNTIFS(A2:A8,">0", B2:B8, "<3")`, you can do:

```py
countifs = ((df['A']>1) & (df['B']<3)).sum()
```

or just call `query` and compute the length of the result.

```py
countifs = len(df.query("A>1 and B<3"))
```

You can also specify the range similar to how range is fed to COUNTIFS using `iloc`:

```py
countifs = len(df.iloc[:8].query("A>1 and B<3"))
```

---

To perform row-wise COUNTIF/SUMIF, you can use `axis=1` argument. Again, the range is given as a list of columns (`['A', 'B']`) similar to how range is fed to COUNTIF.

Also for COUNTIF (similar to the pandas equivalent of COUNTIFS), it suffices to sum over the condition while for SUMIF, we need to index the frame.

```py
df['COUNTIF'] = (df[['A', 'B']] > 1).sum(axis=1)
df['SUMIF'] = df[df[['A', 'B']] > 1].sum(axis=1)
# equivalently, we can use `where` to make a filter as well
df['SUMIF'] = df.where(df[['A', 'B']] > 1, 0).sum(axis=1)

# can use `agg` to compute countif and sumif in one line.
df[['COUNTIF', 'SUMIF']] = df[df[['A', 'B']] > 1].agg(['count', 'sum'], axis=1)
```

[image: res1]

To perform column-wise COUNTIF/SUMIF, you can use `axis=0` argument (which it is by default). The range here (the first 3 rows) is selected using `iloc`.

```py
df.loc['COUNTIF'] = (df.iloc[:3] > 1).sum()
df.loc['SUMIF'] = df.where(df.iloc[:3] > 1, 0).sum()
# or
df.loc['SUMIF'] = df[df.iloc[:3] > 1].sum()
```

[image: res2]

For COUNTIF/SUMIF across multiple rows/columns, e.g. `=COUNTIF(A2:B4, ">1")`, call `sum` twice (once for the column-wise sum and then across columns-sums).

```py
countif = (df.iloc[:4, :2]>1).sum().sum()    # the range is determined using iloc
sumif = df[df.iloc[:4, :2] > 1].sum().sum()  # first 4 rows and first 2 columns
```