# Implementing Excel function countif() in Python on rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DF1 with 100 columns (`col_1` to `col_100`), and I want to put a condition to count only the columns (`col_1` to `col_100`) with value > 50 against every item in column `Item`. In Excel, it's fairly easy - use the function `COUNTIF()`. How can we achieve the same in Python?

```
Item    col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4   col_5   col_6   col_7   …
item_1  10  5   6   9   4   6   77  …
item_2  3   5   66  76  7   89  33  …
```

In above table, outcome should be:

```
Item    Result
item_1  1
item_2  3
```

Comment: `DF1` - can I suppose that you use [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org)?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I do use pandas DF. I've tried a solution available at a previous post pasted below - couldn't really adjust it into my script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643850/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-countif-in-python

Comment: OK. Some clarifications: a) did you saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810526/countif-in-pandas-python-over-multiple-columns-with-multiple-conditions/24811478 ? b) can you share some code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with [DataFrame.transpose()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

```
>>>df
Item    col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4   col_5   col_6   col_7   …
item_1  10  5   6   9   4   6   77  …
item_2  3   5   66  76  7   89  33  …

df1 = df.T
tcol = []

for col in df1.columns:
    tcol.append(len(df1.index[df1[col] > 50].tolist()))

df_total = pd.DataFrame(tcol, columns=['total'])
df = df.join(df_total)
```

**P.S.** There may be a way to do a conditional sum by row but I do not know it off the back of my head. Would be very much appreciated if anyone in the know can point out how!