# Pandas: count number of times every value in one column appears in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the number of times a value in Child column appears in Parent column then display this count in new column renamed child count. See previews df below.

I have this done via VBA (COUNTIFS) but now need dynamic visualization and animated display with data fed from a dir. So I resorted to Python and Pandas and tried below code after searching and reading answers like: [Countif in pandas with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810526/countif-in-pandas-python-over-multiple-columns-with-multiple-conditions) | [Determine if value is in pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value) | [Iterate over rows in Pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) | many others...
but still can't get the expected preview as illustrated in image below.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

#get datasets
path_dataset = r'D:\Auto'
df_ns = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_dataset, 'Scripts', 'data.csv'), index_col = False, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', engine = 'python')

#preview dataframe
df_ns

#tried
df_ns.groupby(['Child','Parent', 'Site Name']).size().reset_index(name='child count')

#preview output
df_ns.groupby(['Child','Parent', 'Site Name']).size().reset_index(name='child count')
```

## preview dataframe

[image]

## preview output

[image]

## expected output

[image]

[Edited] My data

Child = ['Tkt01', 'Tkt02', 'Tkt03', 'Tkt04', 'Tkt05', 'Tkt06', 'Tkt07', 'Tkt08', 'Tkt09', 'Tkt10']

Parent = [' ', ' ', 'Tkt03',' ',' ', 'Tkt03',' ', 'Tkt03',' ',' ', 'Tkt06',' ',' ',' ',]

Site_Name =[Yaounde','Douala','Bamenda','Bafoussam','Kumba','Garoua','Maroua','Ngaoundere','Buea','Ebolowa']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a lookalike of your df.

## Before

[image]

Try this code

```
df['Count'] = [len(df[df['parent'].str.contains(value)]) for index, value in enumerate(df['child'])]
#breaking it down as a line by line code

counts = []
for index, value in enumerate(df['child']):
    found = df[df['parent'].str.contains(value)]
    counts.append(len(found))
df['Count'] = counts
```

## After

[image]

**Hope this works for you.**

Comment: Thank you @Isaac Frank
```
df_ns['child_count'] = [len(df_ns[df_ns['Parent'].str.contains(value)]) for index, value in enumerate(df_ns['Child'])]
```
works just fine. You spiced my weekend! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.
Happy Coding  :D

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have access to your data, I cannot check the code I am giving you. I suggest you will have problems with nan values with this line but you can give it a try.:

```
df_ns['child_count'] = df_ns['Parent'].groupby(df_ns['Child']).value_counts()
```

I give a name to the new column and directly assign values to it through the groupby -> value_counts functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added the data.csv Also trying out your tip