# Replicate Countifs() in pandas with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame of the form:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is a DataFrame that has unique groups and a count of non-zeros for each column 1-9. It would look like the below.

[image]

I'm pretty much at a loss on this. I saw the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions), but this doesn't address the grouping aspect. How can I achieve this using pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
    Group  1  2  3  4  5
0  Group1  0  1  4  0  1
1  Group1  3  0  4  1  5
2  Group2  0  1  4  3  6
3  Group2  5  1  4  0  7
4  Group3  0  0  4  7  8
5  Group3  7  1  4  7  9
```

Solution:

```
In [83]: df.set_index('Group').ne(0).groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()
Out[83]:
    Group    1    2    3    4    5
0  Group1  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
1  Group2  1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
2  Group3  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

as integers:

```
In [84]: df.set_index('Group').ne(0).groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int).reset_index()
Out[84]:
    Group  1  2  3  4  5
0  Group1  1  1  2  1  2
1  Group2  1  2  2  1  2
2  Group3  1  1  2  2  2
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [92]: df
Out[92]:
    Group  1  2  3  4  5
0  Group1  0  1  4  0  0
1  Group1  3  0  4  1  0
2  Group2  0  1  4  3  0
3  Group2  5  1  4  0  0
4  Group3  0  0  4  7  0
5  Group3  7  1  4  7  0

In [93]: df.set_index('Group').ne(0).groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int).reset_index()
Out[93]:
    Group  1  2  3  4  5
0  Group1  1  1  2  1  0
1  Group2  1  2  2  1  0
2  Group3  1  1  2  2  0
```

**Timing:**

```
In [37]: %timeit df.set_index('Group').ne(0).groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.24 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit df.pivot_table(index='Group', aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.2 ms per loop
```

let's test it against a bigger (60.000 rows) DF:

```
In [39]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [40]: df.shape
Out[40]: (60000, 6)

In [42]: %timeit df.set_index('Group').ne(0).groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int).reset_index()
10 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ms per loop

In [43]: %timeit df.pivot_table(index='Group', aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)
10 loops, best of 3: 43 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:**

IMO high-level function `pivot_table` is slower due to additional overhead, but t he difference is not that huge for bigger data sets...

Comment: Smart!... point smoothing... I should do that.  But I'll probably be over the limit again tomorrow soooo

Comment: Meta...  Ask questions...  I know a bit now.  200 points from upvotes is the limit.  Bounties, accepting answers, and answers accepted are exempt.  My main concern is `pandas` upvotes which is not affected by the cap.  That's why I continue answering well after I reach cap.

Comment: An important aspect of this is that each row will ultimately end in zeros, and I would like to preserve all columns. Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: @Kyle, hmm... i can't reproduce it - see UPDATE section

Comment: I was not applying this correctly. This works as expected.

Comment: @MaxU, would you be able to explain why this method is faster than the answer below? Your method averages 1.92 ms on my test DataFrame and the answer below averages 9.54 ms.

Answer (score 2):

Using df from @MaxU solution:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Group', aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)


        1   2   3   4   5
Group                   
Group1  1   1   2   1   2
Group2  1   2   2   1   2
Group3  1   1   2   2   2
```