# Emulating an excel sumifs / multi-criteria index match with dataframes in python / pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, sumifs

I have two dataframes in python using pandas:

- df1: [233,500 x 6] ledger of prices by date
- df2: [1,665,997 x 5] ledger of customer usage by date

On a smaller data set in excel I can simply do the following to create a column on df2 containing each products price on a given date, by row.

```
=SUMIFS(df1[Rate],df1[Date],[@Date],df1[Jurisdiction],[@Jurisdiction],df1[Product],[@Product])
```

Ultimately I want to add a column to df2 (or make a new dataframe with the result) that provides price by matching some criteria in each row (*Jurisdiction, Product Type*) with the same criteria in the price ledger df1.

What's the most appropriate way to associate this data using python and dataframes? Some sort of dictionary and a join?

The examples I've found are mainly dealing with summing given some conditions:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42695/excels-sumifs-implemented-using-pandas-the-python-data-analysis-library
- [Python Pandas counting and summing specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions/20995428)

Bonus: The dates in df1 and df2 will not always match identically. Matching the date in df2 with the most recent price ledger date will need to happen.

Edit: I've include simplified data below to demonstrate how I'm trying to do the most-recent date matching. The date matching is just a middle step towards finding the active price on each date in df2. The direct merge on the two date columns doesn't work because prices are not provided every day.

```
df1:
Date       Price
1/11/2016  5.00
1/12/2016  5.50
1/13/2016  6.00
1/14/2016  7.00
1/16/2016  8.00
1/20/2016  9.00
1/21/2016  10.00
1/22/2016  11.00

df2:
Date       Volume
1/11/2016  100
1/15/2016  100
1/17/2016  200
1/18/2016  300
1/20/2016  200

df3: (df2 with date matching. Cost = Volume*Price)
Date       Volume  MatchedDate  Price  Cost
1/11/2016  100     1/11/2016    5.00   500
1/15/2016  100     1/14/2016    7.00   700
1/17/2016  200     1/16/2016    8.00   1600
1/18/2016  300     1/16/2016    8.00   2400
1/20/2016  200     1/20/2016    9.00   1800
```

Edit 2: The formula provided in the first section in the following works, in excel, with some extra logic to use the first date for df2 entries preceding the first df1 entry. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2601-excel-find-closest-date.html

```
{=MAX((df1[Date]<[@Date])*df1[Date])}
```

Comment: It will be great if you share a small example of both your dataframes and the result you are looking forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply merge the two sets on matching criteria and then run a `groupby` sum:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date', 'Jurisdiction', 'Product'])

merged_df.groupby(['date', 'Jurisdiction', 'Product'])['Rate'].sum()
```

Or with most recent date of *df2*:

```
most_recent_df2 = df2.merge(df2.groupby(['Jurisdiction', 'Product'])['date'].max().reset_index(), 
                            on=['date', 'Jurisdiction', 'Product'])

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, most_recent_df2, on=['Jurisdiction', 'Product'], suffixes=['', '_'])

merged_df.groupby(['date', 'Jurisdiction', 'Product'])['Rate'].sum()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had tried the merge function earlier and was encountering MemoryErrors. Not sure what the difference here was but it worked. Thank you sir.

Comment: I've edited the OP with some more details on the date matching.

The following is about 99% there, but there are ambiguity errors with the use of dataframe columns.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237862/find-the-closest-date-to-a-given-date

Comment: You might need to ask a new question as this strays from SUMIFs with *Jurisdiction* and *Product* criteria. And look into [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof).