# Conditional sum in Python between multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following script, from a larger analysis of securities data,

```
returns_columns = []

df_merged[ticker + '_returns'] = df_merged[ticker + '_close'].pct_change(periods=1)
returns_columns.append(ticker + '_returns')

df_merged['applicable_returns_sum'] = (df_merged[returns_columns] > df_merged['return_threshold']).sum(axis=1)
```

`'return_threshold'` is a complete series of float numbers.

I've been able to successfully sum each row in the `returns_columns` array, but cannot figure out how to conditionally sum only the numbers in the `returns_columns` that are greater than the res`'return_threshold'` in that row.

This seems like a problem similar to the one shown here, [Python Pandas counting and summing specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions), but I'm trying to sum based on the changing condition in the `returns_columns`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks as always!

**EDIT: ANOTHER APPROACH**
This is another approach I tried.  The script below has an error associated with the `ticker` input, even though I think it's necessary, and then produces and error:

```
def compute_applicable_returns(row, ticker):
    if row[ticker + '_returns'] >= row['top_return']:
        return row[ticker + '_returns']
    else:
        return 0

df_merged['applicable_top_returns'] = df_merged[returns_columns].apply(compute_applicable_returns, axis=1)
```

Comment: You want to get the sum of numbers greater than a threshold?

Comment: @SeanPianka, yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` operator for a dataframe should allow you to filter by an expression `df > threshold` and return a dataframe. You can then call `.sum()` on this df.

`df[df > threshold].sum()`

Comment: Sean, thank you for your reply.  I might be misunderstanding what you're suggesting, I'm not experienced with programming - here's what I tried: 

df_merged['applicable_returns_sum'] =  df[returns_columns > df_merged['top_return']].sum()

which gave the error,

TypeError: invalid type comparison

Answer (score 0):

answered the question like this:

```
def compute_applicable_returns(row, ticker):
    if row[ticker + '_returns'] >= row['return_threshold']:
        return row[ticker + '_returns']
    else:
        return 0

for ticker in tickers:
    df_merged[ticker + '_applicable_returns'] = df_merged.apply(compute_applicable_returns, args=(ticker,), axis=1)
```