# Applying conditional COUNTIF to pandas dataframe results in NaN

Tags: python, pandas

If this is a duplicate, please link me to the duplicate. I have not found any other posts that have answered my question.

I have a dataframe, `knn_res`, with the following dimensions and data:

```
            username  Prediction  is_bot
0         megliebsch           1       0                                                                                1         megliebsch           1       0
2         megliebsch           1       0
3         megliebsch           1       0
4         megliebsch           1       0
...              ...         ...     ...
1220     ARTHCLAUDIA           1       1
1221     ARTHCLAUDIA           1       1                                                                                1222     ARTHCLAUDIA           1       1
1223     ARTHCLAUDIA           1       1
1224  ASSUNCAOWALLAS           1       1

[1225 rows x 3 columns]
```

What I would like to do is, for each username, count the number of predictions where `prediction = 1` and where `prediction = 0` and create two new columns with those values. For example using below dataset:

```
| username | prediction | is_bot |
|:--------:|:----------:|:------:|
|    foo   |      1     |    1   |
|    foo   |      1     |    1   |
|    foo   |      1     |    1   |
|    foo   |      0     |    1   |
|    foo   |      0     |    1   |
|   foo1   |      0     |    1   |
|   foo1   |      0     |    1   |
|   foo1   |      0     |    0   |
|   foo1   |      0     |    0   |
|   foo1   |      1     |    0   |
|   foo1   |      1     |    0   |
|   foo1   |      0     |    0   |
|   foo2   |      1     |    0   |
|   foo2   |      1     |    0   |
|   foo2   |      1     |    1   |
```

I would want:

```
| username | count_bot  | count_human |
|:--------:|:----------:|:-----------:|
|    foo   |      3     |      2      |
|   foo1   |      2     |      5      |
|   foo2   |      3     |      0      |
```

where the following logic applies:

> For each row, if `Prediction == 1`, then increase the `count_bot` counter. If `Prediction == 0`, then increase the `count_human` counter. Then, append the totals for each row and group by.

So far, I have tried referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions) and tried the following:

```
knn_res['count_bot'] = knn_res[knn_res.Prediction == 1].count()
print(knn_res)
```

Which yields:

```
            username  Prediction  is_bot  count_bot
0         megliebsch           1       0        NaN
1         megliebsch           1       0        NaN
2         megliebsch           1       0        NaN
3         megliebsch           1       0        NaN
4         megliebsch           1       0        NaN
...              ...         ...     ...        ...
1220     ARTHCLAUDIA           1       1        NaN
1221     ARTHCLAUDIA           1       1        NaN
1222     ARTHCLAUDIA           1       1        NaN
1223     ARTHCLAUDIA           1       1        NaN
1224  ASSUNCAOWALLAS           1       1        NaN
```

Trying:

```
new = knn_res.groupby('username').sum()
print(new)
```

Yields:

```
                 Prediction  is_bot
username
666STEVEROGERS           25      25
ADELE_BROCK               1      25
ADRIANAMFTTT             24      25
AHMADRADJAB               1      25
ALBERTA_HAYNESS          24      25
ALTMANBELINDA            23      25
ALVA_MC_GHEE             25      25
ANGELITHSS               25      25
ANN1EMCCONNELL           25      25
ANWARJAMIL22             25      25
AN_N_GASTON              25      25
ARONHOLDEN8              25      25
ARTHCLAUDIA              25      25
ASSUNCAOWALLAS            1       1
BECCYWILL                 9      25
BELOZEROVNIKIT           17      25
BEN_SAR_GENT              1      25
BERT_HENLEY              24      25
BISHOLORINE              25      25
BLACKERTHEBERR5          11      25
BLACKTIVISTSUS            7      25
BLACK_ELEVATION          24      25
BOGDANOVAO2               7      25
BREMENBOTE               10      25
B_stever96                1       0
CALIFRONIAREP            24      25
C_dos_94                 25      24
Cassidygirly             25       0
ChuckSpeaks_             25       0
Cyabooty                  0       0
DurkinSays                1       0
LSU_studyabroad          24       0
MisMonWEXP                0       0
NextLevel_Mel            25       0
PeterDuca                24       0
ShellMarcel              25       0
Sir_Fried_Alott          25       0
XavierRivera_             0       0
ZacharyFlair              0       0
brentvarney44             1       0
cbars68                   0       0
chloeschultz11           25       0
hoang_le_96               1       0
kdougherty178            25       0
lasallephilo              0       0
lovely_cunt_              1       0
megliebsch               24       0
msimps_15                24       0
okweightlossdna          24       0
tankthe_hank             24       0
```

What am I doing wrong to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby both `username` and `prediction` to separate same values of of columns `username` and `prediction` to groups. `prediction 0` and `prediction 1` will be separated to different groups for each `username`. Call `count` on each group(Note: *I changed from `is_bot` to `prediction` before the `count` because that what you want*). Finally, `unstack` to put `0` and `1` to columns and `rename` them as you want

```
df_out = (df.groupby(['username', 'prediction']).prediction.count().unstack(fill_value=0).
             rename({0: 'count_human', 1: 'count_bot'}, axis= 1))

Out[30]:
prediction  count_human  count_bot
username
foo                   2          3
foo1                  5          2
foo2                  0          3
```

---

Step by step:

groupby each group of `username` and `prediction` and count on each group of `0`, `1` of each `username`

```
df.groupby(['username', 'prediction']).prediction.count()

Out[32]:
username  prediction
foo       0             2
          1             3
foo1      0             5
          1             2
foo2      1             3
Name: prediction, dtype: int64
```

Unstack to put index `prediction` to columns

```
df.groupby(['username', 'prediction']).prediction.count().unstack(fill_value=0)

Out[33]:
prediction  0  1
username
foo         2  3
foo1        5  2
foo2        0  3
```

Finally, rename columns to match your desired output

```
(df.groupby(['username', 'prediction']).prediction.count().unstack(fill_value=0).
    rename({0: 'count_human', 1: 'count_bot'}, axis= 1))

Out[34]:
prediction  count_human  count_bot
username
foo                   2          3
foo1                  5          2
foo2                  0          3
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works for a newcomer like me?

Comment: @JerryM.: I added explanation and step by step detail

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
pd.crosstab(df.username, df.prediction)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, since I also need the counts of when `prediction == 0` and this would sum to 0.

Comment: Question was edited to show results failing for this suggestion. Sorry

Comment: Seems to work when edited slightly, doesn't provide column headings like other answer does, but this is much cleaner.