# How to count Pandas df elements with dynamic condition per row (=countif)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, countif

I am tyring to do some equivalent of COUNTIF in Pandas. I am trying to get my head around doing it with `groupby`, but I am struggling because my logical grouping condition is dynamic.

Say I have a list of customers, and the day on which they visited. I want to identify new customers based on 2 logical conditions

- They must be the same customer (same `Guest ID`)
- They must have been there on the previous day

If both conditions are met, they are a returning customer. If not, they are new (Hence `newby = 1-...` to identify new customers.

I managed to do this with a `for` loop, but obviously performance is terrible and this goes pretty much against the logic of Pandas.

How can I wrap the following code into something smarter than a loop?

```
for i in range (0, len(df)):
    newby = 1-np.sum((df["Day"] == df.iloc[i]["Day"]-1) & (df["Guest ID"] == df.iloc[i]["Guest ID"]))
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions) does not help, as the condition is static. I would like to avoid introducting "dummy columns", such as transposing the `df`, because I will have many categories (many customer names) and would like to build more complex logical statements. I do not want to run the risk of ending up with many auxiliary columns

I have the following input

```
df
   Day     Guest ID
0  3230    Tom
1  3230    Peter
2  3231    Tom
3  3232    Peter
4  3232    Peter
```

and expect this output

```
df
   Day     Guest ID      newby
0  3230    Tom           1
1  3230    Peter         1
2  3231    Tom           0
3  3232    Peter         1
4  3232    Peter         1
```

Note that elements `3` and `4` are not necessarily duplicates - given there might be additional, varying columns (such as their order).

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: Hi, I would make it with 3 steps. a / pandas.shift on date column and name it yesterday or something b/ construct  a flag on Day==Yesterday+1 and GuestId==GuestId c/np.where(flag, "New" , "Returning")

Comment: Also what happens if a customer was there 2 days before?

Comment: If there 2 days before, counts as new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
# ensure the df is sorted by date 
df = df.sort_values('Day')

# group by customer and find the diff within each group
df['newby'] = (df.groupby('Guest ID')['Day'].transform('diff').fillna(2) > 1).astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Day Guest ID  newby
0  3230      Tom      1
1  3230    Peter      1
2  3231      Tom      0
3  3232    Peter      1
```

**UPDATE**

If multiple visits are allowed per day, you could do:

```
# only keep unique visits per day
uniques = df.drop_duplicates()

# ensure the df is sorted by date
uniques = uniques.sort_values('Day')

# group by customer and find the diff within each group
uniques['newby'] = (uniques.groupby('Guest ID')['Day'].transform('diff').fillna(2) > 1).astype(int)

# merge the uniques visits back into the original df
res = df.merge(uniques, on=['Day', 'Guest ID'])

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
    Day Guest ID  newby
0  3230      Tom      1
1  3230    Peter      1
2  3231      Tom      0
3  3232    Peter      1
4  3232    Peter      1
```

As an alternative, without sorting or merging, you could do:

```
lookup = {(day + 1, guest) for day, guest in df[['Day', 'Guest ID']].value_counts().to_dict()}
df['newby'] = (~pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['Day'], df['Guest ID']]).isin(lookup)).astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Day Guest ID  newby
0  3230      Tom      1
1  3230    Peter      1
2  3231      Tom      0
3  3232    Peter      1
4  3232    Peter      1
```

Comment: thanks! this only works if there is exactly one combination of `Day` and `Guest ID`. But it fails when there are multiple rows (i.e., it only finds the first occurrence of "same day, same guest", but not if there are multiple -- I'll update my input posting to include another row to make this clear

Comment: It looks like the merge command kills the indexes... if the former indexes were not [0, 1, 2..] but rather something meaningful, how can I keep them (from the left set, i.e. from `df`)? I tried `left_index=True`, but that resulted in wrong order

Comment: @KingOtto Perhaps this could help, maintain the index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge

Comment: Hm this is not working.. We just sorted the uniques in a different order, and I don't have a link between old and new sorting. So now we would need to introduce yet another column to memorize the order. This is super complex. This is crazy simple in Excel [COUNTIFS(D:D,D3,B:B,B3-1)], where D is the customer column and B is the date column. It is also super easy in a `for` loop. Does Pandas really force me to write 7 lines of code, re-sort multiple times and merge several aux dataframes?

Comment: @KingOtto Do you mean the for loop that you wrote in the question? Are you sure is that what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226190/discussion-between-dani-mesejo-and-kingotto).