# Sum values in a column as long as values from another column are the same

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, binning

Im trying to do the following:
Have a dataframe with columns "Cat" and "Amount". I want to create another column that as long as the values in "Cat" are the same it adds up the differences between the values i and i+1 in the "Amount" column. When the value in "Cat" changes it goes back to 0 and starts again.

Attached an example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions

Comment: kindly provide a copy-paste dataframe, not pics.

Comment: This is a little confusing. Is "Amount" the same as "Value"? Is "another column" the same as "Total by Cat"? Why is the first value for "Total By Cat" 1 for A but 0 for B and C?

Comment: Sorry I attached the wrong picture. YOu are right should be 0 for A. THe column name is Amount (changed if from value.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.Please ignore the value column and total by cat i was trying to replicate your image in excel but i guess the following code should help

```
cat['r']=cat.groupby('Cat').cumcount()
```

[image]

Comment: Also you can use cumsum() and create a new field in case if you want to sum amounts

Comment: Thank you very much Rishabh. I guess this would work but I would have to calculate the differences between the values. Ideally I want to calculate r0+(value1-value0) and so on

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: I just added another picture. Hope is more clear that way. Trying to attach a database  but not sure how to yet (kinda new here). Thank you

Comment: Technically what ever is in the first column you want to subtract it with rest of the values and need a calculation

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your final solution [image: Final Results]

```
cat['Col_count']=cat.groupby('Cat').cumcount()
cat['sum']=cat.groupby('Cat')['Amount'].cumsum()
cat['min_val']=np.where(cat['Col_count']==0,cat['sum'],0)
cat['min2']=cat.groupby('Cat')['min_val'].cumsum()
cat['Cal']=cat['Amount']-cat['min2']
cat
```