# Data Manipulation with respect to date fields to get summary data

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data such as the following:

| start_date | end_date | project_sales | project_category | project_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-08-03 | 2015-08-06 | 1683 | CatA | 1 |
| 2015-08-02 | 2015-08-04 | 6500 | CatB | 2 |

I want to create a timeframe from date 2014-01-01 to 2020-12-01 and assign the details of the above table such as :
For e.g. here I created date_period df from 2015-08-02 to 2018-08-06

| date_period | CatA_project_sales | CatB_project_sales | CatA_No_of_projects | CatB_No_of_projects |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-08-02 | 2166 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2015-08-03 | 2166 | 561 | 1 | 1 |
| 2015-08-04 | 2166 | 561 | 1 | 1 |
| 2015-08-05 | 0 | 561 | 0 | 1 |
| 2015-08-06 | 0 | 561 | 0 | 1 |

As you can see above, project_sales are divided by the number of days it was active.
I am very clear with logic but I'm struggling to come up with the code to support that.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: This code will need to run on huge dataframe dating from 2014-01-01 to 2020-12-31, requesting the help keeping this in consideration

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a `pandas.date_range()` for ceating series of **datetime**

**Function Structure**

> *According to **[pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)***

```
pandas.date_range(start=None, end=None, periods=None, freq=None, tz=None, normalize=False, name=None, closed=None, **kwargs)
```

So, it implement what you're aiming for, you can implement this code for creating series of **datetime** series, after that convert it into **dataframe**.

**Code Syntax**

```
date = pandas.date_range(start="2014-01-01", end="2020-12-31")
dateFrame = pd.DataFrame(date)
dateFrame.columns = ["date_period"]
dateFrame.head()
```

**Output**

```
| date_period |
|:-----------:|
|  2014-01-01 |
| 2014-01-02  |
| 2014-01-03  |
| 2014-01-04  |
|  2014-01-05 |
```

Comment: While its a part of the code but, I'm not just looking for the specific. Still Grateful for help.

Comment: If this a part of what you're looking for. That's because you've not provided more information about what you're looking of how you need the date series merge with the large dataframe you have. 2. The date keys will be merge with... Last but not least, your tried coded which is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check out this Stackoverflow question. I think that you will get the desirable answer there. [Python Pandas counting and summing specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions)