# Pandas counting and suming specific conditions returns only nan

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, sumproduct

I am trying to follow the otherwise excellent solution provided in the thread [pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions), but the code only ever outputs nan values, and with sum (not count), gives a future warning.

Basically, for each row in my df, I want to count how many dates in a column are within a range of +/- 1 days of other dates in the same column.

If I were doing it in excel, the following muti-conditional sumproduct or countifs are possible:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(--(AN2>=$AN$2:$AN$35000-1),--(AN2<=$AN$2:$AN$35000+1)),
```

or

```
=countifs($AN$2:$AN$35000,">="&AN2-1,$AN$2:$AN$35000,"<="&AN2+1)
```

In python, trying the approach in the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions) thread, I believe the code would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'datet': [pd.to_datetime("2020-03-04 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-05 00:00:00"),\
                             pd.to_datetime("2020-03-09 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-10 00:00:00"),\
                             pd.to_datetime("2020-03-11 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-12 00:00:00")]})

df["caseIntensity"] = df[(df['datet'] <= df['datet'] + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) &\
                             (df['datet'] >= df['datet'] - datetime.timedelta(days=1))].sum()
```

The output should be: 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2.
Instead it is wholemeal nan!

Is it correct to assume that because I'm testing conditions, it doesn't matter if I sum or count? If I need to sum, I get a future warning about invalid columns (the columns are valid), which I don't understand. But mostly, my question is why am I only getting nan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead loops in `apply` is possible use vectorized solution, first create numpy arrays chained by `&`, compare and for counts `True`s is possible use `sum`:

```
a = df['datet']
b = a + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
c = a - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    
mask = (a.to_numpy() <= b.to_numpy()[:, None]) & (a.to_numpy() >= c.to_numpy()[:, None])

df["caseIntensity"]  = mask.sum(axis=1)
print (df)
       datet  caseIntensity
0 2020-03-04              2
1 2020-03-05              2
2 2020-03-09              2
3 2020-03-10              3
4 2020-03-11              3
5 2020-03-12              2
```

Here is perfomance for 6k rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datet': [pd.to_datetime("2020-03-04 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-05 00:00:00"),\
                         pd.to_datetime("2020-03-09 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-10 00:00:00"),\
                         pd.to_datetime("2020-03-11 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-12 00:00:00")]})
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [140]: %%timeit
     ...: a = df['datet']
     ...: b = a + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
     ...: c = a - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
     ...:     
     ...: mask = (a.to_numpy() <= b.to_numpy()[:, None]) & (a.to_numpy() >= c.to_numpy()[:, None])
     ...: 
     ...: df["caseIntensity"]  = mask.sum(axis=1)
     ...: 
469 ms ± 16.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [141]: %%timeit
     ...: df["caseIntensity1"] = df.apply(lambda row: get_dates_in_range(df, row), axis=1)
     ...: 
     ...: 
6.2 s ± 368 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @DrWhat - No sure if understand, `I am basically creating a mask with as many columns as rows`

Comment: This extends a good solution you provided elsewhere Mr Jezrael, which I couldn't get to work on this problem. It's also very compact and clear. Please correct me if I am wrong - I am basically creating a np array mask with as many columns as rows in the original series. Each column in the mask considers the defined condition, true or false, for the row. I then simply sum the rows of the mask. Could you please clarify why I need the [:, None]

Comment: @DrWhat - Sure, because is used numpy broadcasting - check [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to sum doesn't match the logic you're trying to apply.

Use the following code:

Create a function which counts the number of days in that range
Call that function for each row and save that as the the value of the new column

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'datet': [pd.to_datetime("2020-03-04 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-05 00:00:00"),\
                             pd.to_datetime("2020-03-09 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-10 00:00:00"),\
                             pd.to_datetime("2020-03-11 00:00:00"), pd.to_datetime("2020-03-12 00:00:00")]})

def get_dates_in_range(df_copy, row):
    return df_copy[(df_copy['datet'] <= row['datet'] + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) &\
                     (df_copy['datet'] >= row['datet'] - datetime.timedelta(days=1))].shape[0]
    
    
df["caseIntensity"] = df.apply(lambda row: get_dates_in_range(df, row), axis=1)


       datet    caseIntensity
0   2020-03-04  2
1   2020-03-05  2
2   2020-03-09  2
3   2020-03-10  3
4   2020-03-11  3
5   2020-03-12  2
```

Comment: Also a very good solution. It works with my real data and could be extended with more conditions similar to a sumproduct or countifs. I'd love to know why pandas (or numpy) don't sum my logic. If I separate or print the logic, its true or false in all the right places.

Comment: While the np.sum method is a lot quicker, I needed to use this sumproduct-like solution when my data got too large, and started causing: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 55.9 GiB for an array with shape (244969, 244969) and data type bool. Thanks again Shubham