# Create dataframe from existing one by counting the rows according to the values in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe,

```
|order_id|customername|product_count|
|1       |a          |2            |
|2       |b          |-1           |
|3       |Q          |3            |
|4       |a          |-1           |
|5       |c          |-1           |
|6       |Q          |-1           |
|7       |d          |-1           |
```

What I want is another dataframe with the count of the rows wherever it is 'Q' in customername and count of the rows with the rest of the items in customername. As given below where test2 represents Q and test1 represents rest of the items. Pecentage column is (total request/count of coustomername)*100, which in this case is (5/7)*100 and (2/7)*100

```
|users|Total request|Percentage|
|test1 |5         |  71.4      |
|test2 |2         |  28.5      |
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20995428/8655058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare column for `Q` and count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), last rename values of index and create `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                   'customername': ['a', 'b', 'Q', 'a', 'c', 'Q', 'd'],
                   'product_count': [2, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1]})
print (df)
   order_id customername  product_count
0         1            a              2
1         2            b             -1
2         3            Q              3
3         4            a             -1
4         5            c             -1
5         6            Q             -1
6         7            d             -1

s = df['customername'].eq('Q').value_counts().rename({True:'test2', False:'test1'})

df1 = s.rename_axis('users').reset_index(name='Total request')
df1['Percentage'] = df1['Total request'].div(df1['Total request'].sum()).mul(100).round(2)
print (df1)
   users  Total request  Percentage
0  test1              5       71.43
1  test2              2       28.57
```

Comment: This solution works but what If I want to add one more column say percentage as I edited in my question statement. How can I do that ?

Comment: I am getting key error : 'Total request' . I used df1 @jezrael

Comment: @user12252991 - do you use `df1` ? created from `df1 = s.rename_axis('users').reset_index(name='Total request')` ?

Comment: I used df1, exactly how you have given the solution.

Comment: @user12252991 - added to answer, for me working well. Can you test data from answer?